# What does the phrase 'proverbial couch' mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a book in English. About emotional intelligence. When I encountered the "Proverbial Couch" phrase, I really got frustrated because I could not find the meaning in any of the dictionaries. I would appreciate if you guide me. the entire paragraph is:

> Much of self-management comes down to motivation, and you can use the expectations that other people have of you as a powerful force to get you up off the proverbial couch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U, Ali."The proverbial couch" is a reference to the term [couch potato](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couch%20potato). Merriam Webster defines it as

> : a lazy and inactive person
>   especially : one who spends a great deal of time watching television

[Proverbial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proverbial) is defined by the Cambridge Dictionary as

> as used in a proverb or other phrase:

So "...to get you up off the proverbial couch" means that the expectations of other people will provide you with the impetus to stop being lazy, stop being a 'couch potato' and make a success of your life.

Comment: I would say the couch has been proverbial – “Get up off your couch and do something” – longer than *couch potato° has been a standard phrase.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Possibly, it might even be the origin of "couch potato" but I've never come across it. Could it be predominently American?